# Enqueue a different css when screen is resized within function.php Wordpress

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I currently have two CSS files which I am loading in the `function.php` of my theme. Those CSS files are 'main.css' & 'mobile.css'. 'mobile.css' is loaded when the screen is at a size minimum or equal to 'max-width: 500px'. The problem is that if I resize a window which >500px to <500px it wont load and override the 'main.css'.

Here's how am enqueuing the files:

```
wp_enqueue_style('mainstyle', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/main.css', array(), '1.0.0', 'all');

wp_enqueue_style('mobilestyle', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/mobile.css', array(), '1.0.0', 'screen and (max-width: 500px)');
```

Is there anyway to load the file and override 'main.css' with 'mobile.css' within the `function.php` file or any other proper way to accomplish this task yet still having the two files separate.

Edit:
It detect when the window is already less than 500px but doesn't if I manually resize a larger window.

I need it to load the CSS when I resize a larger window.

Comment: Have you verified that your `mobile.css` is indeed being loaded? If you're using the same selectors in `mobile.css` that are in `main.css`, then the styles in `mobile.css` will override those in `main.css`. If the selectors in `mobile.css` have a lower specificity than those in `main.css` they **won't be applied** unless it's a property that was not originally defined in `main.css`. You can verify all of this with a browser's Developer Tools.

Comment: You must show your css files and, if possible, some DOM inspection too, is not easy just seeing the php loading.

Comment: @hungerstar The Mobile. CSS isn't loaded if I resize the window. It loads only when the window is already smaller than  500px

Comment: @Carlos Alexandre There's nothing related to thus in the CSS file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason that your style sheet is not being applied is because of the size of the viewport when the page is loaded. According to [**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries):

> When a media query is true, the corresponding style sheet or style
>   rules are applied, following the normal cascading rules. Style sheets
>   with media queries attached to their  tags will still download
>   even if their media queries would return false (they will not apply,
>   however).

This means the rule `max-width: 500px` will evaluate to `false` if the viewport is above `500px` when the page is loaded and `true` when `500px` or less. As stated above, if the evaluation is `false` the style sheet will be downloaded but the styles will not be applied.

Now, I've never used media queries in the `media` tag before and because of the results mentioned above, seem a bit restrictive. The best I can suggest is to wrap your desktop styles in a media query in the file itself and include it separately in the `head` so the evaluation is always true and will be applied when resizing the browser.

```
<link href="/css/mobile.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/css/main.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Example of CSS files:

```
// mobile.css
p {
  color: seagreen;
}

// main.css
@media screen and (min-width: 501px) {

  p {
    color: rebeccapurple;
  }

}
```

Above is an example of mobile first approach where you don't *"contain"* mobile styles to media queries but rather the tablet, desktop etc. styles are.

Here's a [**CodePen demonstrating**](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/eROWLm) the above approach.

Comment: Can you edit and also add, Loading both files at the same time, then add the media query inside the mobile. css

Answer (score 0):

how about setting rules in the stylesheets?

You can create rules in the stylesheets and activate in when a certain criteria is met? You can check this

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp

Something like:

```
@media only screen 
and (min-width: 450px)
and (max-width: 768px) {

    //change whatever element you want    

}
```